# Wrap text in a div around a vertically centered shape

Tags: html, css

Is there any way of wrapping text in a div around a vertically centered shape, like this:
[Text wrapped around a vertically centered shape in a div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/att3Z.png)

The X's represent regular text, with word breaks.

The parent div height is dynamic.

```
<div>
<span><span>
Text Text Text
</div>

<style>
span
{
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
</style>
```

I've tried floating an inner div and using the `shape-outside` CSS property, but couldn't find a way to center it vertically and align it to the right

Comment: share your code

Comment: @Asaf Moshe Check this - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

Comment: Thanks @JanithaRasanga, but there is nothing there about vertically centering the shape, as far as I saw.

Comment: @Asaf Moshe Add some code to your problem.

Comment: @TemaniAfif there isn't really much of a code. I was able to float an inner shape to one of the corners, which is quite trivial. That's it pretty much. I'm looking for a way to center it (or any other solution, maybe without using `float`)

Comment: @JanithaRasanga please see my reply to TemaniAfif. I've shared an image, did you manage to see it?

Comment: center relatively to what? is there a fixed height, a dynamic height, etc. We can provide a lot of solutions but it will be a waste of time we don't have all the requirements and you will later keep adding *no I want this ...* OR *no, my case is not like this*, etc

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The height is dynamic. I will edit the post. Another solution might be giving the floating inner shape 100% height. But this isn't working as well, as the parent height is dynamic.